Ubuntu 22.04 Could not open /dev/vmmon
Tried this solution on Ubuntu 22.04,
openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.priv -outform DER -out MOK.der -

nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=VMWare"
sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n vmmon)
sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n vmnet)
sudo mokutil --import MOK.der
sudo shutdown -r now

it writes

Hover when I start vmware 17.5 it still writes:
Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory.
Please make sure that the kernel module `vmmon' is loaded.


